# Program type already present: androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper$Callback

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx, android-r8

i have a R8 error in android studio with same error:

```
Program type already present: androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper$Callback
```

this is my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.2.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.1.0-rc01'

compileOnly 'org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.5.2'
compileOnly 'org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.2.0'
implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:+'
implementation files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:+'}
```

i must add:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:+'
```

or:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:+'
```

for use TabLayout

but when i add that's implementation , i get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude packages :

```
implementation('com.google.android.material:material:+') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.recyclerview'
}
```